# how to prevent video recording or screen recording in Unity app?

Tags: android, security, unity-game-engine, screenshot, video-capture

I made one java class and binding with Unity main activity. If I take a screenshot then code work fine but when I download any screen recording app and run app then it not Work. But this code works fine with android native App. Also,I search many posts but not found anything that helps me so I created this post.

Here is my Maimainfest file code

```
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.StopRecoding"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
      android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And here is my java code

```
 mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);  
 getWindow().setFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
 android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

 setContentView(mUnityPlayer);Toast.makeText(this, "Activity bind succsesfuly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
Toast.makeText(this, "Activity bind faild " + 
e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: As far as I know `FLAG_SECURE` is the best you can do for Android.

Comment: Thanks sir for the answer but I already mention this not work with unity app with screen recording.

Answer (score 0):

This works in two steps:

1 [Create a custom activity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-custom-activity.html)

**getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);**

```
package my.package;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;

public class SafetyActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
@Override      
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
  }
}
```

2 [Create a custom android manifest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/overriding-android-manifest.html)

**<activity android:name="my.package.SafetyActivity"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application>
        <activity android:name="my.package.SafetyActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application> </manifest>
```